# How to fix "IJ000305: Connection error occured" in jboss

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I'm getting "IJ000305: Connection error occured" warn with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

I have given 6GB heap size, even though getting error.
I'm using jboss server, sqlserver db.
My server and db on different network.
When my server up, it is working fine 15 minutes to 2 hour and after that getting this an error.

Here an error logs:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] - IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@4e483bf8[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@420e4345 connection handles=1 lastUse=1571128295071 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@366288e4 pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@1f3c6fe6[pool=RPAPool] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@7f094ca0[connectionListener=4e483bf8 connectionManager=6b003215 warned=false currentXid=null] txSync=null]: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Unexpected error
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.broadcastConnectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:576)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.connectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:546)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkException(WrappedConnection.java:1635)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkException(WrappedStatement.java:1262)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.checkException(WrappedResultSet.java:4063)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getString(WrappedResultSet.java:1385)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor288.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy730.getString(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:66)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:332)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2873)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1600)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1500)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:712)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:940)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2111)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3887)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:458)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:427)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:260)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1078)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2424)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:978)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:903)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:891)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:879)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor532.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy693.merge(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:397)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor529.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy714.save(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor647.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy715.save(Unknown Source)
at com.rpa.jobs.ExecuteScheduledProcess.updateRobotHeartBeat(ExecuteScheduledProcess.java:45)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor605.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:257)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:149)
at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:193)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:416)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:481)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:616)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:4053)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:226)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:144)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2099)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2084)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getString(SQLServerResultSet.java:2441)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getString(WrappedResultSet.java:1381)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor288.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy730.getString(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:66)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:332)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2873)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1600)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1500)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:712)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:940)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
```

Comment: It can be a sign of memory leak. My advice is to analyze your application behavior with Java VisualVM which is provided with JDK and check for suspicious memory behavior.

Comment: Okay, i'm checking, thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is

`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Which might be a memory leak, I would first increase the size of the heap and try again.
If you continue to increase and it continues to fail is likely a memory leak.

You can get at a heap dump and analyze it with `Eclipse MAT`.